# close waiting dialog in c# when event occured

Tags: c#, winforms, progressdialog

In socket programming that we wait for data receive, i show a dialog that with show method(i do not show it with show dialog method because event is not occured.)

Psudo code:

```
buttonClick()
{
    socket.Send(array byte)
    waitingForm.Show();
}

recieveCompletedEventHandler()
{
    WaitingForm.Close();
}
```

It is ok, but user can access the form controls and because the waiting form is not modal.i just want a sample code that when i send bytes and all data received and event occur and the waiting form close. And of course the waiting form be modal when data does not receive completely.

Comment: I don't understand why can't you run your long operation in the background, and use `ShowDialog` ?

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Comment: There is not enough information for me to create an example based on your scenario. What i meant was to start your job in the background: `Task.Run(yourSocketOperation);` and then use the `ShowDialog`

Comment: i just when i click button and data send with socket, i show a modal waiting dialog. and it close when an event occur. just this.all code that need has been wrote in question.h just wanna open modal waiting dialog in button click and close it with and event.h wanna be modal dialog because h want the user cant access the parent form.

Comment: So, still i don't understand why can't you use `ShowDialog`?

Comment: thank you. i made mistake. it now work with your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ofir Winegarten for answer
i create a sample and put the code here for others

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void funDel();

    private waiting waitForm;

    private event funDel funEvent;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        funEvent += Form1_funEvent;
    }

    private void Form1_funEvent()
    {

       waitForm.Close();
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (InvokeRequired) // Line #1
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => button1.Text = "Proccessing"));

            }

            else
            {
                button1.Text = "Proccessing";
            }

        });

        waitForm = new waiting();
        timer1.Start();
        waitForm.ShowDialog();

    }



    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        funEvent();
    }
}
```